# Android MediaCodec CodecException while configure

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I receive an exception when trying to configure for a AVC encoder. I need to shutdown and re create the codec when the video stream resolution changes. Does anyone have inputs for the exception below:

```
10-14 15:10:20.934 E/OMX-VENC(  980): async_venc_message_thread interrupted to be exited
10-14 15:10:20.944 I/OMX-VENC(  980): Component Deinit
10-14 15:10:20.944 I/OMX-VENC(  980): Video encode perflock released
10-14 15:10:20.944 I/ACodec  ( 3824):  [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] Now uninitialized
10-14 15:10:20.944 I/ACodec  ( 3824):  [] Now kWhatShutdownCompleted event : 7062
10-14 15:10:20.944 I/MediaCodec( 3824): Codec shutdown complete
10-14 15:10:20.944 I/ACodec  ( 3824):  [] Now uninitialized
10-14 15:10:20.944 I/ACodec  ( 3824): [] onAllocateComponent
10-14 15:10:20.944 I/OMXClient( 3824): Using client-side OMX mux.
10-14 15:10:20.954 I/OMX-VENC(  980): Video encode perflock acquired,handle=1635
10-14 15:10:20.954 I/OMX-VENC(  980): Component_init : OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc : return = 0x0
10-14 15:10:20.954 I/ACodec  ( 3824): [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] Now Loaded
10-14 15:10:20.964 W/System.err( 3824): android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xffffec77
10-14 15:10:20.964 W/System.err( 3824):     at android.media.MediaCodec.native_configure(Native Method)
10-14 15:10:20.964 W/System.err( 3824):     at android.media.MediaCodec.configure(MediaCodec.java:1778)
10-14 15:10:20.964 W/System.err( 3824):     at com.slingmedia.stcapture.model.SCCaptureCameraSource.setupVideoCodec(SCCaptureCameraSource.java:1172)
```

Comment: I added retry attempts to get over the issue.

Comment: Did it help? what resolution you are trying to  record? What device? I have similar problem.

Comment: The issue was incosistent, so I cannot say for sure if it is completely resolved. But, in any case it will allow the MediaCodec (used in async mode) some more time to get into proper state.

I am recording on a Samsung S6 at 1080p 30fps.

Comment: In my case it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: have the same issue with SM-G903W, any news?

Comment: To help anyone else who finds this I was getting the same issue it failed consistently with a hi def file (h264 (High) 3840x2160) 

I tried another sample, same codec, smaller res and consistently no problems (h264 (High) 1920x1080).

I think this may be a problem with allocating resources.